# Как прописать или/или в grok(logstash)?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, logstash, grok

Есть вот такой лог:

`<30>Jun  8 16:47:02 oem-virtual-machine dbus-daemon[668]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'`

Пытаюсь сделать вот что:
1)Если есть слово Successfully или, например failure, то записывать либо первое, либо второе слово в поле. Не понимаю как это сделать регулярным выражением. Также, например с пробелами: в одном логе есть лишний пробел, в другом совершенно таком же, нет. Больше они ничем не отличаются, но надо, чтобы их парсинг осуществлялся одним регексом.

2)Строчка 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'. Если она есть, то записывать в какое-нибудь поле. Если нет, то лог все равно парсится и ничего никуда не записывается.

Пока написал только вот это:

`%{MONTH}\s\s%{MONTHDAY}\s%{TIME}\s%{HOSTNAME:[alertix][host]}\s%{NOTSPACE:[alertix][process][name]}:\s%{NOTSPACE}\s(Successfully|Failure)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
%{MONTH}\s+%{MONTHDAY}\s+%{TIME}\s+%{HOSTNAME:[alertix][host]}\s+%{NOTSPACE:[alertix][process][name]}:\s+\[%{NOTSPACE:level}\]\s+(?<status>Successfully|Failure)[^']*(?:'(?<namespace>[^']*)')?
```

**Подробности**

- Все `\s` заменены на `\s+`, чтобы совпадение было найдено несмотря на количество пробелов между словами
- В `\[%{NOTSPACE:level}\]` квадратные скобки вынесены за пределы группы
- `(Successfully|Failure)` заменено именной захватывающей подмаской `(?<status>Successfully|Failure)` для создания отдельного поля (я назвал его `status`, но вы можете изменить это название)
- `[^']*(?:'(?<namespace>[^']*)')?` находит

  - `[^']*` - ноль и более символов отличных от `'`
  - `(?:'(?<namespace>[^']*)')?` - необязательная незахватывающая подмаска:

    - `'` - одиночная кавычка
    - `(?<namespace>[^']*)` - Именная захватывающая подмаска "namespace", находит ноль и более символов отличных от `'`
    - `'` - одиночная кавычка

Comment: Спасибо большое. А подскажите пожалуйста, я правильно понимаю, что символ "^" означает отрицание? Т.е. грубо говоря "не знак одиночной кавычки".

Comment: @chasesilvers `[^']` - любой символ кроме `'`. Здесь символ "карет" означает отрицание, `[^...]` — это отрицающий символьный класс.